# How to create a RTL (right to left) tweet button

Tags: javascript, css, string, twitter, right-to-left

I have a RTL (Arabic) blog with a tweet button that utilizes the title to populate tweets.

The issue is that twitter shows the LTR version of the title and the [Twitter web intent](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=JSON%20Stringify%20-%20%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%84%20%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%86%20JSON%20%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85%20JS%0A%0Ahttps://www.freecodecamp.org/arabic/news/json-sstr-kyfy-thlyl-kyn-json-bstkhdm-js/) does not seem to have an option to pass text direction.

Here is what I see:
[image]

Here is what I should see (modified twitter styles):
[image]

And here is the actual string without styling: 'JSON Stringify - كيفية تحليل كائن JSON باستخدام JS'

Comment: Twitter strings do not seem to recognise the RTL. You will see this if you try to mix Arabic and English text inside a tweet; it will have messed-up output.

Comment: adding an Arabic word at the beginning of the title might help.